# scaling axes in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm sure this is an incredibly simple question but I've recently started using Mathematica so it's all new to me. How do you scale the y axis? I try the following but it won't compile.

```
Plot[y = {Exp[-(x^2+3x+2)]}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Are you trying to limit the range of the plot to 0<y<1 or are you trying to make the y scale read 0<y<1, with out changing what is being plotted?

Comment: If your question was answered, you should select one as 'Answered'.

Answer (score 10):

The [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) option is what you are looking for.

`Plot[-x^2+3x+2, {x,0,5}, PlotRange->{0,1}]`